# storing the output of boost::bind in a boost::function

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

I currently have something like this

```
void asomeMethod(int q)
{
    std::cout << "Method with parameter " << q ;
}

int main()
{
     boost::function<void(int)> parfunct;
     parfunct = boost::bind(&asomeMethod,12);
     parfunct;  //Does not call asomeMethod ??
    return 0;
}
```

I want to call the function ptr but the method is not being called ? Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `boost::function<void()>`, since there's no remaining argument.

Then call it like a function:

```
parfunct();
```

Comment: in that case I get Error `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Sorry, fixed. Extraneous arguments in `bind` are ignored, subtle error... The `function` type needs to be what you *call*, not the input of `bind`.